# Named anchor jump menu last item position not positioned towards the top

Tags: html, css, menu, anchor, named

Does anyone have a CSS solution to have the last item in a named anchor link list orient the content towards the top? The only way I have found to get this to work is to have plenty of empty space below the last item. Is this the best way of doing this? The only other thing that may work would be to use JS to force the position on the last item click.

https://jsfiddle.net/jacoblett/ejdy4ncd/embedded/result/

https://jsfiddle.net/jacoblett/ejdy4ncd/

CSS

```
.header {border:1px solid black;background-color:#e2e2e2;position: fixed; top: 0;}

            .anchor {height:150px;}

            article {margin:200px 0;width:600px;}

            .anchor{
              display: block;
              margin-top: 0; 
              visibility: hidden;
            }
```

HTML

```
            <div class="header">
            <h1>Named anchor jump link menu</h1>
            <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
            <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <span class="anchor" id="section1"></span>
            <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>

            <span class="anchor" id="section2"></span>
            <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>

            <span class="anchor" id="section3"></span>
            <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            </article>
```

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is because there isn't enough room to scroll down to the final element. That's why added space makes it go "higher". Perhaps you could bring attention to it with another method, such as highlighting it with a color or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this is what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/ejdy4ncd/23/

To explain a little:

1. Your problem is dependent on the screen height, so the solution is also based on screen height.
2. I removed `<span>` because it was only included to artificially create space. It's a bad practice to muddle content and presentation. Use the margin / padding in CSS instead.
3. I replaced the markup with semantic tags. You had things like `<div class="section">` instead of `<section>`. And `#section1, #section2, #section3` are actually `<span>` tags. Very confusing :S

Comment: Thank you for your help. You both answered my question in that you have to have room below the last item for it to work. It just looks odd when you scroll down the page and see all of the empty space. I was not aware of the calc function.